# Kendo Scheduler Mobile Mode display Invalid data events

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

[image: Display in wrong places]

I am developing a calendar view using kendo scheduler and need to view this from web and apple iPad mini. When displaying the data in tablet it display the entered events in wrong places simply out of the calendar time ranges. But working correctly in web. I use the same code except the additional code line `Mobile(MobileMode.Tablet)`, please refer the attached images and my code line for more details.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Portal.Presentation.Web.BoundedContext.QC.MVC.Areas.Razor.Models.LeavePlanModel>()
              .Name("scheduler")
              .ShowWorkHours(true)
              .WorkDayStart(08,30,00)
              .WorkDayEnd(19,30,00)
              .WorkWeekStart(1)
              .WorkWeekEnd(5)
              .Date(@DateTime.Now)
              .StartTime(08,30,00)
              .EndTime(19,30,00)
              .Height(600)
              .Views(views =>
                         {
                             views.DayView();
                             views.WorkWeekView(workWeekView => workWeekView.Selected(true));
                             views.WeekView();
                             views.MonthView();
                         })
              .Events(e =>
                          {
                              e.Save("scheduler_save");
                              e.Remove("scheduler_remove");
                              e.Edit("scheduler_editMobile");
                              e.MoveStart("scheduler_moveStart");
                              e.ResizeStart("scheduler_resizeStart");
                              e.DataBound("scheduler_dataBound");
                              e.Cancel("scheduler_cancelLeave");
                          })
              .Mobile(MobileMode.Tablet)
              .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
              .Resources(resource =>
                             {
                                 resource.Add(m => m.OwnerId)
                                     .Title("Resource")
                                     .DataTextField("Text")
                                     .DataValueField("Value")
                                     .DataColorField("Color")
                                     .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Read("GetInspectors", "LeavePlan"));

                                 resource.Add(m => m.LeaveType)
                                     .Title("Leave Type")
                                     .DataTextField("Text")
                                     .DataValueField("Value")
                                     .DataColorField("Color")
                                     .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Read("ReadLeaveType", "LeavePlan"));
                             })
              .DataSource(d => d
                                   .Model(m =>
                                              {
                                                  m.Id(f => f.OwnerId);
                                                  m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                                                  m.Field(f => f.OwnerId).DefaultValue(1);
                                                  m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                                                  m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceId);
                                              }).Read(x => x.Action("Read", "LeavePlan").Data("SchedulerFilter.OnSearch"))))
            </div>
```